# How to do contrasts with weighted observations in R's linear model function lm()

Tags: r, linear-model, contrasts

As part of a simple simulation study, I have the following lines of code in R:

```
>contrasts(mySample$Stratum) = contr.sum(13)
>UnweightedLM <- lm(y ~ Stratum, data=mySample)
>WeightedLM <- lm(y ~ Stratum, weights=wts, data=mySample)
```

where y is a random normal variate and Stratum is a factor. I indicate to R that I want deviation contrasts in the first line. temp1 and temp2 should give different results, I would have thought, if the rows are weighted differently. The standard errors do come out different, as it happens. (for the curious, this is part of a larger attempt on my part to understand the survey package).

Here is code for a toy example illustrating the problem:

```
library("survey")
y <- rnorm(100,2,1.5)
Stratum <- factor(rep(1:5, each=20))
stratumSize <- rep(c(100,400,150,200,80), each=20)
mySample <- data.frame(y, Stratum, stratumSize)
mySample.design <- svydesign(id=~1, data=mySample, strata=~Stratum, fpc= ~ stratumSize)
mySample$wts <- weights(mySample.design)
 UsualContrasts <- lm(y ~ Stratum, data=mySample)
 summary(UsualContrasts)
 contrasts(mySample$Stratum) = contr.sum(5)
UnweightedLM <- lm(y ~ Stratum, data=mySample)
WeightedLM <- lm( y ~ Stratum, weights=wts, data=mySample)

summary(UnweightedLM)
summary(WeightedLM)
```

Here is some output for UnweightedLM

```
Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
```

(Intercept)   2.0488     0.1409  14.540   <2e-16 ***
Stratum1      0.2061     0.2818   0.731    0.466
Stratum2     -0.2614     0.2818  -0.928    0.356
Stratum3      0.2597     0.2818   0.922    0.359
Stratum4     -0.3881     0.2818  -1.377    0.172

And here is what I get from WeightedLM

```
Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
```

(Intercept)   2.0488     0.1570  13.049   <2e-16 ***
Stratum1      0.2061     0.3543   0.582    0.562
Stratum2     -0.2614     0.2233  -1.171    0.245
Stratum3      0.2597     0.3031   0.857    0.394
Stratum4     -0.3881     0.2740  -1.416    0.160

The estimates are the same, although the standard errors are different. Note that the so-called Intercept estimate (actually an estimate of the mean), is the sample average. This would not be the case if the strata were of unequal size. The intercept from UsualContrast is different, which shows that my Contrast command is doing something. But why don't I get different results according as there are or are not weights?

I was originally going to post this on Stackoverflow, but then it seemed that maybe my problem is not understanding how contrasts work, as distinct from not understanding how R works.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this has anything to do with how the factor `Stratum` is coded in the model matrix $X$.

W.l.o.g.$^\star$ let's consider the *means model* where the design matrix $X$ is an incidence matrix with five columns corresponding to the strata (= levels of `Stratum`) and in which each observation is represented by a binary row vector with a single entry of $1$ in the column (= stratum) to which it belongs.
In this parameterization $X^\top X$ and its inverse are diagonal.

Since the *weights are identical for each observation within the same stratum*, $X^\top WX$ (where $W$ is a diagonal matrix with the observation weights as main-diagonal entries)  is just a scaled version of $X^\top X$ with the $j$-th entry in the main diagonal scaled by the weight of the $j$-th stratum. Hence,
$\left(X^\top WX\right)^{-1}$ is just a scaled version of $\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1}$ where each main-diagonal entry is scaled by the inverse of the corresponding stratum weight.

```r
WeightedLM_2 <- lm(y ~ 0 + Stratum, weights = wts, data = mySample)
X <- model.matrix(WeightedLM_2)
W <- diag(WeightedLM_2$weights)

solve(t(X) %*% W %*% X)
#          Stratum1 Stratum2    Stratum3 Stratum4 Stratum5
# Stratum1     0.01   0.0000 0.000000000    0.000   0.0000
# Stratum2     0.00   0.0025 0.000000000    0.000   0.0000
# Stratum3     0.00   0.0000 0.006666667    0.000   0.0000
# Stratum4     0.00   0.0000 0.000000000    0.005   0.0000
# Stratum5     0.00   0.0000 0.000000000    0.000   0.0125
solve(t(X) %*% X)
#          Stratum1 Stratum2 Stratum3 Stratum4 Stratum5
# Stratum1     0.05     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
# Stratum2     0.00     0.05     0.00     0.00     0.00
# Stratum3     0.00     0.00     0.05     0.00     0.00
# Stratum4     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.05     0.00
# Stratum5     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.05
unique(WeightedLM_2$weights)
# [1]  5.0 20.0  7.5 10.0  4.0
```

Similarly, $X^\top W$ is a scaled version of $X^\top$ in which each column (i.e., row of $X$) is scaled by the weight of the stratum to which it belongs. Clearly, the scalings vanish in the matrix product $\left(X^\top WX\right)^{-1}X^\top W$ and thus $\left(X^\top WX\right)^{-1}X^\top W = \left(X^\top X\right)^{-1}X^\top$.

This shows the the weighted least squares estimator $\left(X^\top WX\right)^{-1}X^\top Wy$ and the ordinary least squares estimator $\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1}X^\top y$ coincide in the given situation.

---

$^\star$ Your model is just one possible reparameterization of the means model. The estimates of the regression coefficients in a model with a particular coding for `Stratum` can be recovered from the estimates in the means model via

```r
solve(cbind(1, contrasts(mySample$Stratum))) %*% coef(WeightedLM_2)
```